# How to consume a local Web API in one project from a local MVC project in the same solution? (.NET 6)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 solution which has 2 separate projects, a MVC project and a Web API.

Currently when I try consuming the API I get this error:

> The response ended prematurely

I'm not sure whether this could be due to my configs, due to some kind of security feature, or due to the fact that I'm just running this on my machine. I've tried looking at all these possibilities and searched and tried and I am just stuck.

I have setup my startup projects so that isn't the issue. There is no other environment than my local machine (dev)

I've tried:

- changing to multiple different URLs from the launch settings
- changing the Http Client version to 20
- adding JSON SerializerOptions:

  ```
    var options = new JsonSerializerOptions(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web);
  ```
- adding a cors policy to the DI container:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("ApiCorsPolicy", builder =>
{
   builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:52927").AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
}));

app.UseCors("ApiCorsPolicy");
```

- adding an http client handler (since I'm not going to be hosting this any time soon)

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = HttpClientHandler.DangerousAcceptAnyServerCertificateValidator;
```

- adding a ServicePointManager Security Policy:

  ```
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
  ```
- Disabling HTTPS

[image: MVC Controller]

[image: API Controller]

[image: API Controller]

[image: API Config]

API Launch Settings URLS:

- Project App URL
- IIS Express URL
- IIS Express SSL:

Which of these should I use? I've tried all of them.

I don't believe this issue is in any way related to the MVC portion including the post request, but I could be wrong. Do I need to publish them both to run on IIS in order to make this work? Any help solving this would be greatly appreciated.

```
Stack Trace:

at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.<SendAsyncCore>d__64.MoveNext()
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.<SendWithVersionDetectionAndRetryAsync>d__84.MoveNext()
at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.<SendAsyncCore>d__8.MoveNext()
at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredValueTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.<SendAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<<SendAsync>g__Core|83_0>d.MoveNext()
at RPA.Controllers.LoginController.<ValidateLogin>d__4.MoveNext() in C:\Users\Mitch\Desktop\Projects\RPA\RPA\Controllers\LoginController.cs:line 51
```

Error:

> An error occurred while sending the request. The response ended prematurely.

**Edit**:

I have found this message which is weird because I haven't enabled anything for JWT unless its enabled on default:

[JSONWebToken Payload Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDmZu.png)

**Edit 2**:

[Network Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIgyK.png)

**Edit 3**:

I've tried allowing anonymous endpoint access:

```
    //apiconfig (program.cs)
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.MapControllers().AllowAnonymous();
    app.UseSwagger();
    //app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
else
{
    app.MapControllers();
}
```

LoginServiceController with the [AllowAnonymous] attribute

Comment: i believe no special configuration is required to launch both together; it's quite a common configuration. Could it be that you're trying to access an HTTP link through HTTPS?

Comment: That was something I considered but I disabled app.UseHttpRedirection() in the apiconfig. I will look to see if there are additional HTTPS settings I need to take care of.

Comment: Running directly in vs2022, you can test it, you don't necessarily need to deploy it to IIS right away, we all know that Visual Studio can also use IISExpress to start projects.

Comment: Judging from the sample code provided so far, you commented out the CORS settings and need to enable it. Also, please provide an error message in the console in your browser.

Comment: I tried to implement it and i commented it out because it didn't make the difference. Do I need to enable it if I'm communicating within my own solution? I've edited in the error message and stack trace.

Comment: So it appears to be something to do with "jwt Payload was not valid JSON." I tried using some JSON Serializer Options but that didn't do the trick. I will keep investigating.

Comment: Hi Frehroshaka, do you mind create a brand new sample project for us? For this issue, we need to debug it. If it's a study/trainning project, that's will be great. Please hide you sensitive information, thanks for your understanding.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Can you connect to and interact with the HTTP API via other HTTP clients? Try e.g. making a query with cURL. What happens then?

Comment: please inspect developer window of your browser, particularly the network tab to see what's going on. are there any console messages? when you click the request on network tab, what do you see in the response?

Comment: how exactly are you sending the request? is the request being sent through the browser or is it a back-channel communication?

Comment: @JasonPan I've created a new web api project in my solution. what would you have me do from here?

Comment: @MarkSeemann I tried making several cURL requests using all the different localhost urls in the launchsettings and nothing came from it. I've never used cURL so maybe I did it incorrectly?

ex: 
curl -d '{"UserName" : "a", "Password": "b"}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:44364/api/LoginService/ValidateLogin

Comment: @EmreBener I've checked my network tab and I get a 500 error. I've edited in a screenshot of my network tab. Also I'm unsure of what you mean by a back channel communication. I believe its just browser based as i'm just doing a post request from a mvc controller to the url of my api service controller

Comment: If you got the same error from a raw HTTP request, it's likely that you can rule out the calling code. May I suggest that you look into the HTTP response status code?

Comment: 500 error means the request is received by the other server, but an internal error occurred, possibly before the request even made its way to the controller. I doubt there is much anyone can really do here to help you because the post is incredibly long despite having little to zero useful information regarding what you are exactly doing (screenshots really don't help). please rewrite the question, and instead of focusing on all the million things you have tried, explain what exactly you are trying to do, and how exactly you tried to do it (with no screenshots)